# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock being returned in response but not being run by the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using the following to try and execute some JavaScript when an update panel has completed its request:

```
script = String.Format("SparkBase.Html.ScrollToElment('{0}');", clientID)
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "Focus_" & clientID, script, True)
```

The JavaScript does actually show in the HTTP Response, however the browser doesn't execute it.

```
|76|scriptBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|SparkBase.Html.ScrollToElment('ctl00_CPMain_lblErrorOptionalExtraQuantity');
```

I've run the JavaScript code manually in the console and it works.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651342/updatepanel-startup-script-not-executing help?

Comment: It turns out my piece of code was being run, however subsequent to that some .NET code scrolls the page back to where it began. It happened so quickly I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
script = String.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>SparkBase.Html.ScrollToElment('{0}');</script>", clientID)
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "Focus_" & clientID, script, True)
```

you are missing the `script` tag in string..